# Mapping Alt+Key to move to same indent

Tags: vim, macvim

Im having issues mapping the following keys on my `vimrc` not really sure why. I've checked and it doesn't seem to be there other mappings using the same keys, but for some reason the following doesn't work:

```
" Move to next/previous line with same indentation
nnoremap <A-k> :call search('^'. matchstr(getline('.'), '\(^\s*\)') .'\%<' . line('.') . 'l\S', 'be')<CR>
nnoremap <A-j> :call search('^'. matchstr(getline('.'), '\(^\s*\)') .'\%>' . line('.') . 'l\S', 'e')<CR>
```

Any obvious error here?
The commands themselves do work as i've tested.

Answer (score 0):

In OSX, and probably in other OS's also, alt+(something) will actually send a different key,

In my keyboard, alt+j and alt+k will actually send ¯ and „ respectively. So you will either need to use the actually sent keys or a different key combination.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use gnome tweak tool to map keys. Its a gui interface.

To install :

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: Im on OSX, and have a similar tool to map keys. Was looking for a solution that would require that though.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing ALT + key sends an 'ESC' before 'key'. If you are in insert mode, upon pushing ALT + key you will return to normal mode and then your key stroke will be actioned in normal mode.

Try it!

If (in insert mode of course) you type 'abcde  ' then ALT + 0, you will find yourself in normal mode at the start of the line.

So, two things:

1. ALT + k is, actually, ESC + k, which will just be 'k' (line up) in Normal mode... but will also be 'k' (line up, in normal mode) when executed from insert mode. This is what you have seen.
2. This, adopted as a practice, can be kinda useful, if you want to do "change me to normal mode and do keystoke 'x' " actions from insert mode.

Comment: Not sure if it's because of my environment MacVim/OSX but ALT+K does not send me to normal mode, it just inserts the weird character I mention above. 
Anyway the goal is to have this motions working on Normal mode, not insert.

Comment: I didn't see your mention of these weird characters being inserted (edit: ah, no, yes, now I have). ALT+key should send ESC then key - hence (other, other than your) problems with mappings using the ALT key

Comment: Jesus, I can't figure your last comment. :)
Anyway, on my setup it doesn't seem to be sending the ESC command as you mention.